# No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?a

Tags: web-applications

M very new to JAVA.
Trying to build an app using spring mvc.
m just trying to create an simple form to register a quartz job.

JobController.java

```
    package com.shopzilla.monitor.controller;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
    import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
    import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
    import org.quartz.JobDetail;
    import org.quartz.JobKey;
    import org.quartz.Scheduler;
    import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
    import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
    import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import com.shopzilla.monitor.form.QuartzJob;
    import com.shopzilla.monitor.form.RequestJob;
    import com.shopzilla.monitor.service.Alert_Generator;
    import com.shopzilla.monitor.service.JobGen;
    import com.shopzilla.monitor.service.JobService;

    @Controller
    public class JobController {

@Autowired
private JobService JobService;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {
    System.out.println("Called");
  map.put("RequestJob", new RequestJob());
    map.put("Joblist", JobService.listJob());

return "Monitor";
}



@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("RequestJob")
RequestJob RequestJob, BindingResult result) {
    String URL = RequestJob.getURL();
    String Locator = RequestJob.getLocator();
    String regex = RequestJob.getRegex();
    String Threshold = RequestJob.getThreshold();
    String recipient = RequestJob.getRecipient();
    String Frequency = RequestJob.getFrequency();
    String Alarmif = RequestJob.getAlarmif();


    String vlaue1=null;
    String jobName = "Job_"+System.currentTimeMillis();
    String jobGroup = "Group1"; 
    Alert_Generator Alarm = new Alert_Generator();
    try {
        vlaue1=Alarm.Monitor(URL, Locator, regex, Threshold, recipient,Alarmif,jobName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //configure job


    JobKey jobkey = JobKey.jobKey(jobName, jobGroup);

    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(JobGen.class)
            .usingJobData("URL", URL)
            .usingJobData("Locator", Locator)
            .usingJobData("regex", regex)
            .usingJobData("Threshold", Threshold)
            .usingJobData("recipient", recipient)
            .usingJobData("Alarmif", Alarmif)
            .withIdentity(jobkey).storeDurably().build();


    Date startTime = new Date();
    CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
             .withIdentity(jobName)
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
            .build();
    try {
        //Schedule Job
        SchedulerFactory schdFact = new StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties");  
        Scheduler scheduler = schdFact.getScheduler();  
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    return "redirect:/index";
}


@RequestMapping("/delete/{Job}")
public String deleteContact(@PathVariable("contactId")
String JobName,String JobGroup) {

    JobService.removeJob(JobName, JobGroup);

    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

}

RequestJob.java

```
            package com.shopzilla.monitor.form;

    public class RequestJob {
    public String URL;
    public String Locator;
    public String regex;
    public String Threshold;
    public String recipient;
    public String frequency;
    public String Alarmif;
    public String getAlarmif() {
        return Alarmif;
    }
    public void setAlarmif(String alarmif) {
        Alarmif = alarmif;
    }
    public String getURL() {
        return URL;
    }
    public void setURL(String uRL) {
        URL = uRL;
    }
    public String getLocator() {
        return Locator;
    }
    public void setLocator(String locator) {
        Locator = locator;
    }
    public String getRegex() {
        return regex;
    }
    public void setRegex(String regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }
    public String getThreshold() {
        return Threshold;
    }
    public void setThreshold(String threshold) {
        Threshold = threshold;
    }
    public String getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }
    public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }
    public String getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }
    public void setFrequency(String frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }
    }
```

web.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
        <display-name>Monitoring Tool</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    <!--    <listener>  -->
    <!--     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  -->
    <!-- </listener> -->


    </web-app>
```

Monitor.jsp

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Monitoring Tool</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
            .data, .data td {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid #aaa;
                margin: 2px;
                padding: 2px;
            }
            .data th {
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color: #5C82FF;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Job Manager</h2>

    <form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="RequestJob">

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="URL"></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="URL" /></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="Locator"></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="Locator" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="regex"></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="regex" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="Threshold"></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="Threshold" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="recipient"></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="recipient" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="frequency"></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="frequency" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    </form:form>


    <!-- <h3>Jobs</h3> -->
    <%-- <c:if  test="${!empty Joblist}"> --%>
    <!-- <table class="data"> -->
    <!-- <tr> -->
    <!--    <th>JobName</th> -->
    <!--    <th>jobGroup</th> -->
    <!--    <th>strjobKey</th> -->
    <!--    <th>nextFireTime</th> -->
    <!--    <th>&nbsp;</th> -->
    <!-- </tr> -->
    <%-- <c:forEach items="${Joblist}" var="contact"> --%>
    <!--    <tr> -->
    <%--        <td>${Joblist.jobName} </td> --%>
    <%--        <td>${Joblist.jobGroup}</td> --%>
    <%--        <td>${Joblist.strjobKey}</td> --%>
    <%--        <td>${Joblist.nextFireTime}</td> --%>
    <%--        <td><a href="delete/${Joblist.jobName,Joblist.jobGroup}">delete</a></td> --%>
    <!--    </tr> -->
    <%-- </c:forEach> --%>
    <!-- </table> -->
    <%-- </c:if> --%>


    </body>
    </html>
```

When i run this project i get

```
    SEVERE: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:76)
        at org.apache.jsp.Monitor_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(Monitor_jsp.java:163)
        at org.apache.jsp.Monitor_jsp._jspService(Monitor_jsp.java:100)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    Apr 13, 2014 10:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/MonitoringTool] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /Monitor.jsp at line 29

    26: 
    27: <h2>Job Manager</h2>
    28: 
    29: <form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="RequestJob">
    30: 
    31:     <table>
    32:     <tr>
```

please help me out with this problem. Completely blocked due to this

Comment: What beans are defined in spring-servlet.xml? Where is JobService bean defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the log: 
WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
...
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:76)
...

RequestContext instance(i.e., JspAwareRequestContext) provides access to current state like the WebApplicationContext.
RequestContextAwareTag is superclass for all tags that require a RequestContext. (Spring form() tag  is a subclass of org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag).

getRequiredWebApplicationContext method in WebApplicationContextUtils always finds the root WebApplicationContext for this web application, which is typically loaded via ContextLoaderListener. Each DispatcherServlet has its own WebApplicationContext, which by itself is not a root WebApplicationContext but inherits all the beans already defined in the root WebApplicationContext.

In your scenario you have not defined root WebApplicationContext (i.e by ContextLoaderListener) and so the error. 
Include the below code in web.xml:

```
    <!--Root web application context-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

And create an empty applicationContext.xml as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd      
    </beans>
```